# Hover image transition (fade) to a title - HTML

Tags: html

I am currently coding on brackets and notepad++ to create a very basic HTML Website. My question is how am I able to hover over an image (which is also a link to another page) in my nav bar (my nav bar consists of photos, not text) and have the image do fade transition into text. I cannot do CSS nor can I for this project. I need it to be able to integrate this code with my other coding I already have (so not create a new image in the process).

Comment: You need to provide us the code, what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)